# What is the meaning of 'well'?(in this context)

Tags: meaning

He then conveyed him and his sister into the veriest old well of a shivering best-parlour that ever was seen, where the maps upon the wall, and the celestial and terrestrial globes in the windows, were waxy with cold.(A CHRISTMAS CAROL)

Comment: the well, like a water well, a damp hole in the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled for definitions of "well" that would fit and I found this which I believe to be correct:

> an enclosed space in the middle of a building, giving room for stairs or an elevator, or to allow light or ventilation.

https://www.google.com/search?q=well+definition